# how to call the methods of a parent class in a child class object without overriding in child in java script

Tags: javascript, inheritance, overriding

Let's say I have a parent and a child class as shown below.

```
class Person { 

  constructor(name) { 
    this.name = name
  }

  greeting() { 
    console.log(`Hi! I'm ${this.name}`); 
  };

}

class Teacher extends Person { 
  constructor(first, subject) { 
    super(first); 

    this.subject = subject; 
  }
}
```

now lets say I create a global object of the child class

```
globalThis.teachers = new Teacher("Roby", "Math")
```

this global object can directly access the parent class property name. So, I can call,

```
globalThis.teachers.name \\Will contain Roby
```

But can I call the method of the parent class, greeting() like this directly without overriding it like the following way?

```
globalThis.teachers.greeting() \\Will print in console
```

Snippet:

```js
class Person { 

  constructor(name) { 
    this.name = name
  }

  greeting() { 
    console.log(`Hi! I'm ${this.name}`); 
  };

}

class Teacher extends Person { 
  constructor(first, subject) { 
    super(first); 

    this.subject = subject; 
  }
}

globalThis.teachers = new Teacher("Roby", "Math") 
console.log(globalThis.teachers.name);
globalThis.teachers.greeting();
```

Is it like every parent class method that I want to access, I will have to override it in the child and from there I will have to call
super.greeting().

Comment: It seems irrelevant to your question that the variable is a *global* object, but yes you can call the superclass method without overriding. Did you try? What happened?

Comment: I did, but it says no function found

Comment: I added the code in a runnable snippet in your question: it works fine. Can you edit the snippet so that it reproduces the problem you encounter?